# Xively request working on cUrl but not with HttpParty

Tags: ruby, curl, httparty, xively

I am trying to use Xively with Ruby without their API, for two reasons:
- the ruby API is not documented
- using API endpoint not documented too

So I can send some information using curl (see: https://xively.com/dev/tutorials/curl/ ) , with the following request:

```
curl --request PUT --data @content.json --header "X-ApiKey: <API_KEY>" --verbose https://api.xively.com/v2/feeds/1895459373
```

This works fine

The exact same content, send through HTTP  Party:

```
res=HTTParty.post("https://api.xively.com/v2/feeds/1895459373",{
            :body => JSON.dump(content),
            :headers => {"X-ApiKey" => API_KEY,'Content-Type' => 'application/json'}})
```

I have this answer:

```
{"title"=>"Forbidden", "errors"=>"You do not have the necessary permissions to access this resource"}
```

In both case, the content of the body is exactly the same. I've tried with others HTTP client and none seems to works, only curl works fine...

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: Would this gem make things easier for you? https://github.com/xively/xively-rb

Comment: @SteveTurczyn as I said, the gem is undocumented except for one sample, and give no clue on how to send update to multiple feed in a single call, so it's useless.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I misread your question.  How is `API_KEY` set?  The curl example is manual command line?

Comment: API_KEY is se if the correct value, I can use for example HttpParty to get info on the feed (https://xively.com/dev/docs/api/data/read/single_feed/ ).

It's the write part that does not work (https://xively.com/dev/docs/api/data/write/ )

Also, I've made some test with the competing ubidots they have the same type of API, it works well so it's seems to be something really specific to Xively that is not exaplained anywhere....

Comment: Are you sure that key has write access?

Comment: yes, as I said the same post works well with curl,same key, same payload